# What is the use of ROLES in Azure Syanpse if I cannot add any USER to it?

Tags: sql, azure, azure-synapse

I am creating users, in particular, login_id in Azure synapse using Admin login id and password.

As of now, I have to give permission individually to every login using the code below.
**(brown_batman is a user created in login_id brown_batman for database adventure2016)**

```
grant Select,Alter,Update,Execute,Insert on database::[adventure2016] to brown_batman;
```

I am creating a role and giving permissions to that role in adventure2016 DB using the code below:

```
CREATE ROLE Perm;  
grant Select,Alter,Update,Execute,Insert on database::[adventure2016] to Perm
```

Now, if I try to add users to the role using code `ALTER ROLE Perm ADD Member brown_batman;`  then I get the error

**Parse error at line: 1, column: 17: Incorrect syntax near 'ADD'.**

I am really trying to understand the use of roles when I cannot add users to a specific role.

Comment: docs use 'alter role db_owner Add member alias' to achieve this - this isn't an answer more a comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the doco here;

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/sql-authentication?tabs=serverless

> In Azure SQL Database or synapse serverless, use the ALTER ROLE statement.

```
ALTER ROLE db_owner ADD MEMBER Mary;
```

I assume you aren't using serverless, so you need to use this syntax:

> In dedicated SQL pool use EXEC sp_addrolemember

```
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', 'Mary';
```

Comment: Is'nt Azure synapse comes with a Serverless SQL pool. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/on-demand-workspace-overview. @Nick

Comment: Yes it does. Are you using it? Going by your error you aren’t.

Comment: Okay, so I have the option to choose from a Dedicated SQL pool or Serverless SQL Pool.
AzureDW is in use before I joined, so yeah, basically, they may have chosen a Dedicated SQL pool.
@Nick

Comment: Then use the syntax for a dedicated pool.